# NINA B1 firmware update from 3.0.1.1 to 4.0.0

Tags: bluetooth-low-energy

I try to update many time with no success.

I am having error in loading the NINA-B11X-BOOT3.0.1.zip using UART.

Any of you found a solution?

[image]

Comment: You need to supply a lot more info for us to be able to help. E.g. can you show the exact error you are seeing.

Comment: have you done any research before you posted your question? ... are you sure that you are upgrading from ver 3.0.1.1?

Comment: yes I am sure. And I read all the ublox documentation on the web. Here is the related question on the ublox portal https://portal.u-blox.com/s/question/0D52p00008HKDhI/max-mtu-transfert-on-ninab1-firmware-3011
I still need to test with using nrfGo from Nordic